# Карусель с возможность скролла полосой прокрутки

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо реализовать карусель с автоскроллом, но возможностью дополнительно перелистывать элементы полосой прокрутки, аналогично здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/yh1r2tjm/29/

В примере используется плагин Swiper Slider, но проблема в том, что я не могу добавить анимацию автоскролла.
Есть ли примеры и/или возможность решения с плагином Swiper Slider?

Добавлял банальную CSS анимацию:

```
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0)
  }
```

От части такой подход работает, но скроллится без движения ползунка и только один раз (не зацикленно).
P.S - более желательно решение без сторонних плагинов, на чистом JS/CSS.

Comment: что такое "совпадения" в текущем контексте и от чего зависит?

Comment: Это не сортировка, а трансформация одного массива в другой. Вы в своём же комментарии выше написали решение. Ну так реализуйте его

Comment: А где ваш способ решения? Добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, использовать самописный вариант лучше.
Но данный слайдер ([Swiper](https://swiperjs.com)) советую к использованию, к тому же на нём можно реализовать много чего.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  speed: 400,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  autoplay: {
   delay: 5000,
   pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
  },
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
    dragSize: 20
  },
});
```

```css
@import url('https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css');

.max-wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 7.5px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  max-height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-slide::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.swiper-control {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-control > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
  position: static;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.swiper-button-next::after, .swiper-button-prev::after {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-scrollbar.swiper-scrollbar-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  width: auto;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="max-wrap">
  <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 1</span></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 2</span></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-control">
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```